# Hibernate criteria for many-to-many entity property

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

```
@Entity
class A {

@ManyToMany
private List<B> list;
...
}

@Entity
class B {
...
}
```

I'd like to get list from A class using criteria (not sql query). Is it posible to do this? Projection in this case does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, The Criteria only allows selecting the root entity, and not any joined entity. It would thus be easier if your ManyToMany was bidirectional. You could the use the criteria equivalent of

```
select b from B b inner join b.as a where a = :theA
```

If that's not an option, I think the only way is to use a subquery, and thus code the criteria equivalent to

```
select b from B b where b.id in (select b2.id from A a inner join a.list b2 where a.id = :theAId)
```

The code would thus look like this:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(B.class, "b");

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "a");
dc.createAlias("a.list", "b2");
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("a.id", theA.getId()));
dc.setProjection(Projections.property("b2.id"));

c.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("b.id", dc));
```

Comment: Also notice that the IN statement is sometimes limitated by your SGDB (for exemple i think in Oracle we can only put 1000 values on an IN statement). Perhaps you'd better run a separate query to get the list,  then split it in sublists (guava partition function?) and run your subquery againt all the sublists

Comment: The IN statement uses a subquery in this case, and not a list of literal values. There isn't any limitation on the number of items returned by the subquery in this case.

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to call (assuming a is instance of A)

```
a.getList();
```

If the A class has been set up with appropriate getter setter. I don't see the need for Criteria query.

Comment: It's not because you can do that with objects that it can't be useful to be able to do it with an SQL/HQL/Criteria query, for performances issues for exemple...