# Hibernate Projection for mapped properties

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate while projecting :

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(XYZ.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("XYDId", 1)).add(Restrictions.eq("active", Boolean.TRUE));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("abc.id").as("id"));
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("abc.timezoneKey").as("TIMEZONEKEY"));
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(abc.class));
```

throwing an exception

`could not resolve property: abc.timezoneKey of: com.locaid.gfe.common.entities.XYZ`

although In XYZ entity abc is present as proerty and in abc timezoneKey is present as a property. Can anyone help me in getting what I am lacking.

Comment: can u elaborate it a bit , I have not got exactly what to use

Comment: Thanks For your support I have got a good solution for this .adding all projection in a projection List and then setting the projection List in criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `alias` for the `abc` property

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(XYZ.class, "xyz").createAlias("xyz.abc", "xabc").add(Restrictions.eq("xyz.XYDId", 1)).add(Restrictions.eq("xyz.active", Boolean.TRUE));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("xabc.id").as("id"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("xabc.timezoneKey").as("TIMEZONEKEY"));
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(abc.class));
```

You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533466/hibernate-criteria-for-many-to-many-entity-property).

Comment: Thanks For your support I have got a good solution for this .adding all projection  in a projection List and then setting the projection List in criteria.